# NSUrlConnection doesn't work. I don't get any response

Tags: objective-c, ios

In my class I create a CBUrlConnection:

```
urlConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[urlConnection start];
```

but I don't get any response, these delegate methods are never invoked:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFinishLoadingData:(NSData *)data error:(NSError *)error
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didUpdateProgress:(CGFloat)percent
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
```

The request seems to be correct, the server url is surely correct, and the server is working correctly. What could be wrong ?

Comment: Did you add `NSURLConnectionDelegate` to the list of protocols your class adopts?

Comment: Are you trying to use the connection inside of an NSOperation subclass?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just fixed it... it was because the code wasn't running on the main thread.

For who might be interested I've solved with:

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can absolutely run an `NSURLConnection` from inside an `NSOperation`.
The actual trick is that an `NSURLConnection` needs a run loop. See http://www.cocoaintheshell.com/2011/04/nsurlconnection-synchronous-asynchronous/ and https://stackoverflow.com/a/6238764/171933

- Johannes