# AFNetworking Set runLoopModes?

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking

AFNetworking default runLoopModes is NSRunLoopCommonModes.I want use NSDefaultRunLoopMode,and set it

```
 operation.runLoopModes = [NSSet setWithObject:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

But it doesn't work. when I scroll the scrollView,download task still running.
Anybody can help me? thanks.

Comment: I have never used AFNetworking and I guess that this operation running in another thread, not in main thread

Comment: so you want to pause network operations in tracking runloop mode, but why?

Comment: yes,I want to pause network operations,when scrolling the scrollview.because network may effect scrollview's response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently I encountered similar question, while I was implementing images lazy loading in UITableView. User scrolling should have higher priority here.

Your direction is correct, the problem is in runloop modes. With UIImageView+AFNetworking extension, images are loaded with AFURLConnectionOperation, which is working on a separate network thread (see implementation), so NSURLConnections are running not on main thread.

To make the tasks stop when UITrackingRunLoopMode is active, you need to **move networking code on main thread** somehow.

Possible solutions:

1. Setup default runloop mode for your request operation.

   ```
   AFImageRequestOperation *requestOperation = [[AFImageRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest];
   [requestOperation setRunLoopModes:[NSSet setWithObject:NSDefaultRunLoopMode]];
   ```
2. Put connection on main thread (that's ok, NSURLConnections are running their own threads): Find `+ (NSThread *)networkRequestThread` and make it return `[NSThread mainThread]`. That might be not suitable with other situations, beware locks.

I am still not sure why AFNetworking is creating it's separate network thread. To process incoming data in background? If anybody have a guess, please reply.

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841880/async-nsurlconnection-concurrent-nsoperation-when-to-use-nsrunloop) question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a way to don't modify AFNetWoring's code?

Comment: I think there is. I just have looked over Facebook's Three20 sources and found this: they override NSOperationQueue 'suspend' property. All it does is "determines if new load requests are allowed to reach the network". On scrollViewWillBeginDragging you do [operationQueue setSuspended:YES], on scrollViewDidEndDragging you resume [operationQueue setSuspended:NO].

Answer (score 1):

So here we go, alternative solution, without hardcoded injection. Assuming you are using UIImageView+AFNetworking extension:

```
// user began scrolling
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    [[UIImageView af_sharedImageRequestOperationQueue] setSuspended:YES];
}

// user released finger and scrolling animation is finished
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    [[UIImageView af_sharedImageRequestOperationQueue] setSuspended:NO];
}
```

Also check out Foursquare's [solution](https://github.com/foursquare/fully-loaded/blob/master/Classes/FullyLoaded.m), which relies on the same technique.